# Conditions on a matrix having 1 as eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $m\geq n$, and assume $A (A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ has 1 as an eigenvalue.
Is it possible to say anything about the structure of A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P := A(A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top$ is the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $A$. Orthogonal projections are idempotent ($P^2=P$) and symmetric ($P^\top = P$) and you can check that the only eigenvalues of $P$ are $0$ and $1$. So actually, $1$ is always an eigenvalue of your matrix (except in the case when $A$ is the zero matrix).

Comment: Thank you, for reference I add the explanation of why https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253630/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-for-orthogonal-projection/1253637

Comment: just for other readers,  when writing "you can check that the only eigenvalues of A are 0 and 1"  you mean "P" and not "A", isn't it?

Comment: @FabioDallaLibera Yes, thank you for catching that typo